# click event can't be listened in fullscreen in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <video src="http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/movie.mp4" controls="controls" loop="loop"></video>
    <button style="z-index:2147483647;position:fixed;">play/pause</button>
</body>

<script>
    var video = document.querySelector('video')
    var button = document.querySelector('button')

    button.onclick= function(e){
        video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause()
    }
</script>
</html>
```

In Chrome for Mac:
The "button" can  work in no-fullscreen；not working in full-screen.
Why and How? 
(Chrome 64.0.3282.140 )

Comment: Not sure what happens with chrome, but you seem to be writing your own controls anyway. So go ahead and get rid of the original ones. Create a fullscreen button which will call Element.requestFullscreen from the common parent of your video and your controls. This way, you'll be able to handle perfectly how your controls get displayed in fullscreen mode, and you won't have such *bug*.

Comment: It works for me in fullscreen here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bpw324fp/

Comment: @Barmar but not work for me,I guess we don't have a same version chrome

Comment: Chrome 64.0.3282.140 on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: @Barmar Chrome 64.0.3282.140 on OS X High Sierra 10.13.3
amazing,maybe chrome is innocent....

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome 64 High Sierra at BrowserStack, it also worked.

Comment: Have you tried it with all your Chrome extensions disabled?

Comment: @Barmar i tried with all Chrome extensions disabled, but this problem still exists，how confusing

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar I can also reproduce this issue. Even right clicking the `<button>` returns the Shadow elements of the `<video>`.  Are you sure you are in the video's fullscreen mode?

Comment: I was in Chrome's full-screen mode, by clicking on the green button.

Comment: The bug occurs when you are in the video's FS mode :-) And arguably, the real bug is that you are able to see the button.

Comment: OK, now that I understand, I do reproduce it.

Comment: It works in Safari. In Firefox, the button doesn't show in full-screen mode.